# LiveData observer not get called

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

ViewModel, Repository and Dao class are mentioned below.

Instantiate Viewmodel in Fragment.

```
playlistVideoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PlaylistVideoViewModel.class);
playlistVideoViewModel.getAllPlaylistVideos(String.valueOf(currentBucketId)).observe(this, new PlaylistSongObserver());
```

View Model class:

```
public class PlaylistVideoViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<List<PlaylistSong>> allPlaylistSongs;
private PlaylistVideoRepo playlistVideoRepo;


public PlaylistVideoViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    playlistVideoRepo = new PlaylistVideoRepo(application);
    allPlaylistSongs = new MutableLiveData<>();
}


public LiveData<List<PlaylistSong>> getAllPlaylistVideos(String playlistId) {
    new GetPlaylistSongs().execute(playlistId);
    return  allPlaylistSongs;
}

public void delete(String path) {
    playlistVideoRepo.delete(path);
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class GetPlaylistSongs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        allPlaylistSongs.postValue(playlistVideoRepo.getAllPlaylistSongs(strings[0]));
        return null;
    }
}}
```

Repository:

```
class PlaylistVideoRepo {
private final PlaylistSongDao playlistSongDao;

PlaylistVideoRepo(Application application) {
    AppDatabase appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    playlistSongDao = appDatabase.playlistSongDao();

}

public List<PlaylistSong> getAllPlaylistSongs(String playlistId) {
    return playlistSongDao.getAllPlaylistSongs(playlistId);
}

public void delete(String path) {
    new DeletePlaylistVideoAsyncTask(playlistSongDao).execute(path);
}}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface PlaylistSongDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + PlaylistVideoConstants.TABLE_NAME +
        " WHERE " + PlaylistVideoConstants.Columns.PLAYLIST_ID + " = :playlistId")
List<PlaylistSong> getAllPlaylistSongs(String playlistId);

@Query("DELETE FROM "+ PlaylistVideoConstants.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + PlaylistVideoConstants.Columns.PATH + " = :path")
void delete(String path);}
```

Now issue is whenever i am going to delete any data. I am not receiving any callback in my observer.

Please rectify if I am doing wrong anything.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are observing `allPlaylistSongs`. When you are deleting by path, you are never updating that `MutableLiveData`. There are a couple of ways you could solve your problem.

1. You could simply update that `MutableLiveData` whenever you are deleting a song. So you could either reload all songs from repo by executing `GetPlaylistSongs` task again.
2. You could manually remove it from the list and then notify the `MutableLiveData`.
3. You could change your Dao to actually expose `LiveData` instead of just value. That way any changes in the database will be propagated to your observers.

Example:

```
@Dao
public interface PlaylistSongDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + PlaylistVideoConstants.TABLE_NAME +
        " WHERE " + PlaylistVideoConstants.Columns.PLAYLIST_ID + " = :playlistId")
LiveData<List<PlaylistSong>> getAllPlaylistSongs(String playlistId);

@Query("DELETE FROM "+ PlaylistVideoConstants.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + PlaylistVideoConstants.Columns.PATH + " = :path")
void delete(String path);}
```

By changing it to `LiveData` you would now be able to remove the `GetPlaylistSongs` task and you could directly pass down the `LiveData` object to Repository and then down to Fragment (of course applying any transformations you may need).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with your first point. Replying to your third point. Before using MutableLiveData I was using LiveData returning from DAO for observing. But had same Issue that's why I moved to MutableLiveData.